# Make REST API return ID of ManyToMany relationship object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

in my User class I have the following code

```java
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private transient Set<Ticket> activeTickets;
// Setters & Getters
```

The reason this has to be transient is due to the Ticket class also having a list of users, hence causing infinite recursion if i requested the user or the ticket, the user would request the tickets which would request the users which would request the tickets etc etc.

ATM due to it being transient its just not shown, to make my REST API more accessible, would it be possible to display all the ticket IDs, instead of the ticket objects?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the transient keyword and using the appropriate Jackson annotations for this scenario: [@JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion#managed-back-reference).